# How to build a JPA jhipster application where entities are populated from another jhipster application?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jhipster

Here's a simple example of two microservices: 
a) provide information about a person from a database
b) provide information about an order and a person from a database where the order is stored and it only has a reference to a person by an id

The correct SOA way is not to replicate the person in the second service because we don't want data replication. So my question is, how to implement in service b) a model for order and person. But the full person information is populated from service a)?

Please provide an exmaple. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer nor an example, just a hint. I would go with a DTO of the person to decouple the implementation of service a from its interface. This person DTO could be located in a service a interface artifact (e.g. maven module), which would then be a dependency of service b. Or if you want to be more flexible, just put the person DTO into service b as the java representation of the rest api.